# How do I use WiX Toolset to abort an uninstall if a specified service is running?

Tags: wix

I've created an installer for a Windows Service using WiX.  The installer installs and configures the service with no issues.  It also uninstalls the service with no issues if it's not running.  If the service is running, it may or may not stop and uninstall the service with no issues depending on how long it takes the service to stop.

What I'd like to do is check if the service is running on uninstall, and if so, display a message and then rollback the uninstall.  I was looking at the WiX Toolset documentation but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: Have you looked into why the service isn't stopping in a timely manner?

Comment: The service calls a stored procedure which can take quite a while to run.  I have no control over the stored procedure.

Comment: Does the service really need to wait for the results of that  stored procedure?   A windows service is expected to respond to service control manager messages in a timely manner.  That default is 30 seconds but can be changed in rare circumstances.  Note this is a system wide change. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922918/a-service-does-not-start-and-events-7000-and-7011-are-logged-in-window

Comment: The service needs to know whether to move a file into a "processed" folder or an "error" folder.

Comment: can it wait until next start to do that?